# combine contents of files from multiple directories into a single text file in Mac OSx

Tags: macos, file, cat, subdirectory

I have a complicated scenario. In my current working directory, I have several subdirectories. Each subdirectory has a number of files, but I'm only interested in one: `RAxML_bestTree.best`. The file name is the same for each corresponding file in every subdirectory, i.e., they are not unique. Thus, a copy command to a new subdirectory will not work since one `RAxML_bestTree.best` will be shown and overwritten 514 times.

I need to take the content of each subdirectory's `RAxML_bestTree.best` and have it placed into a file `all_RAxML_bestTrees.txt` either in the current working directory or a new subdirectory. I have tried the following, which appears to print the contents to screen but not to file:

`find . -type f -name \RAxML_bestTree.best -exec cat {} all_RAxML_bestTrees.txt \;`

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, found my issue:

`find . -type f -name \RAxML_bestTree.best -exec cat > all_RAxML_bestTrees.txt \;`